# Retrieve 'first day of week' and 'CalendarWeekRule' from environment

Tags: c#, vb.net

This should be easy, I think, but I couldn't find it (yet) myself.

I need to know if these two values can be retrieved from the system's environment and/or local settings.

I know that in my country (The Netherlands) these values should be:

- FirstDayOfWeek = Monday
- CalendarWeekRule = FirstFullWeek

But I don't want to set a fixed rule for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could retrieve these values from the `DateTimeFormat` object.

```
CultureInfo theNetherlands = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-nl");
var firstDayOfWeek = theNetherlands.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
var calendarWeekRule = theNetherlands.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule;
```

If you want to get these values for the current culture you could just use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DatetimeFormat`.